# Symbol not showing in QGIS legend in csv imported file

Tags: qgis, symbology, csv, import

I've been looking for a similar question to my problem, but all ended with the "check coordinate system" answer. I import a csv file with semi-colon delimiters.
My problem is that coordinate system is correct, decimal character is comma (checked in the import window) and the legend shows me the layer with all the points (even if I classificate by field) and the symbol does not show. To be sure, I do a zoom to layer and it fits all supposed points in the file, but the symbol, neither the point, appears in the legend or map. I don't think is a coordinates issue, maybe a representation issue. It worked with older versions of QGIS, but not in the recent versions (used 3.16 and updated to 3.24 and now trying 3.22)This is how the representation window appears[image] and the final legend [image]

Comment: under simbolo you need to create a master symbol. The ramp will affect the fill colour of set symbol

Comment: Thank you, you were also wright in your answer. Is it a normal procedure?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right that it is not a projection issue.

Looking at your screenshot it seems like a master symbol was not created for some reason.

See numbers on screenshot below:

1 - Create a master symbol in here

2 - Delete all existing symbol classes

3 - Regenerate symbol classes

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solved the issue, but I think there must be an error in the system that makes not creating the master symbol, neither in the csv loaded file or in any shp loaded. Thanks again